# Can I read the anonymous object which I supply in the MapControllerRoute in a middleware class"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

in my .NET 6 MVC project I have this route:

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    "Error",
                    "error",
                    new { controller = "Error", action = "Index", anonymousProperty ="3" });
```

Is it possible to read the anonymous object (and thereby the `anonymousProperty`) in my custom middleware?

I've looked in the RouteData `context.GetRouteData();` but it doesn't show up there.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the `defaults` parameter here? I suspect this would be much easier if you used the `dataTokens` parameter.

Comment: There is actually a very good reason that I use the `defaults` parameter here! Kidding, there is not, I didn't know about the `dataTokens` :-). Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but be sure that your middleware is placed after `UseRouting` call if you have explicit one:

```cs
app.UseRouting();
app.Use(async (context, func) =>
{
    var routeValue = context.GetRouteValue("anonymousProperty"); // 3 for route .../error
    await func();
});
```

Comment: Excellent! That's what I missed, I registered the middleware BEFORE the `UseRouting`!. Thanks very much.